# PHP Form Question - creating form that allows user to send web site information to a friend

Tags: php, forms, share

Edit-

Thank you for your prompt responses. Specifically what I want to achieve is for me to have setup an html page whose sole purpose is to be grabbed by the form the user has filled and is then put inside the body of an email and sent to the person the user has chosen. I would format that html page to be very simple. I don't know if that narrows it down more.

Hi,

I have to create 2 forms one is a typical php contact form which I have completed but the other one needs to allow the user to send a compacted version of the site's information to a friend. "Share this site" kind of link. My client sent me a sample where you input the recipient's email address, the sender's email, name and message and the recipient receives an html email with the compacted information. I am not an expert and I just finally got the hang of the basic contact form. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Gianfranco

Comment: Can you give us a more specific question?

Answer (score 1):

More specifics would definitely help here, I can't figure out if you want to send part of the $_POST[] data to another user or actually share the content on the page w/ another user.

If you wish to fire off the $_POST[] data (or some of it) just include a loop to build up var/val combos and send them off to another user as part of your processing routine.  The code for that would be something like this:

```
// set headers
$sheaders = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// generate $_POST[] summary for email
$smsg = NULL;
foreach ($_POST as $svar => $sval)
{
  if(!empty($sval))
  {
    $smsg .= "$svar : ".htmlspecialchars($sval)."\n";
  }
}

mail('blah@spam.com', date("m/d/Y")."-Submission", $smsg, $sheaders);
```

If you are talking about mailing the content on the page I think just a simple submit that sends the link to the current page would be a good solution, particularly due to the fact that all email clients render HTML differently (or not at all) so sending a link is a sure fire way to get people back to your proper content.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses. Specifically what I want to achieve is for me to have setup an html page whose sole purpose is to be grabbed by the form the user has filled and is then put inside the body of an email and sent to the person the user has chosen. I would format that html page to be very simple. I don't know if that narrows it down more.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need four things for this:

1. A form that allows the input of "sender's e-mail", "recipient's e-mail", "name" and "message". This should also include some link to the page they wish to send (whether this is a URL, and ID, etc, you just need some way to identify this. It is a good idea to send this passively to the form.) You'll have to decide where and how to display this (for instance, on it's own page, on each content page, as a pop-up, as a hovering box, etc).
2. A script that can pull relevant parts of the page in question for e-mailing. For instance, if it is just an image, with a caption, you may only want the image and the caption (not the heading bar, navigation bar, anything like that). For an article, you may want to send the entire text, or you may want to only send a snippet. I've found the simplest way to do this do make sure that actual content is in some `$content` like variable, which you can parse as you see fit.
3. An e-mail template that you can inject the data from item #2 into. This may be a blank e-mail, an e-mail that is similar to your site, with your site's title, colors, etc, or something completely different. That's up to you.
4. An e-mailing script that can send the e-mail from item #3 to the e-mail from item #1, with the additional fact that the e-mail must be labeled as sent from the "sender's e-mail" from step #1. This would be accomplished with e-mail headers.

When you have all of these steps, it's relatively simple, acquire the necessary data from the form in item #1. Gather the required item data from step #2 given the identifier passed to the form in item #1. Load the e-mail template, and inject the data from items #1 and #2 into it, then construct the necessary headers comprised of the user details in item # 1. Then send this e-mail to item #4 for delivery.

You are asking a very broad question, and this is the best way that I can answer it without more details., I would suggest you look into each one of these item's individually, as it will help reduce your work load and give you a more flexible, extendable and robust script.